# Can I Connect My Android App To Communicate Directly With Firebase Or More Practical To Create REST Api service

Tags: android, rest, firebase

Thanks for such a wonderful platform of experts and helpful people, I am looking towards making a cross platform application for a contest at the IEEMADC app dev challenge, but we selected Android as native instead of Website first.

Now I found firebase to my rescue, but maybe because I'm not an expert I think the app is a bit more than just updating/creating Json calls, I have completely modelled this app already and it's a sort of Linked In kind of app.

My question is that, can I, should i, and how professionally practical is it to make methods/classes on android sdk that communicate and exchange data directly with Firebase? And as time goes on to find a Node.js developer to make its web platform and call the same data from Firebase or better still I make the whole REST api using PHP/MYSQL as server side and then communicate without firebase. Thanks guys I'm hoping to get great answers from everyone.

Comment: yes you can easily connect to firebase or can use PHP/MYSQL for server side depending on what you prefer to use. both things you can easily achieve in android. Since from question it seems you're more comfortable in PHP/MYSQL here is really great tutorial :
http://www.androidhive.info/2012/01/android-login-and-registration-with-php-mysql-and-sqlite/

Comment: Thanks a lot I'm pretty much comfortable with PHP/MYSQL, satisfying answer. But would I be able to still use Firebase features even in my REST api

Comment: what do you mean by use firebase inside your REST api. can you explain a bit more??

Comment: I mean can I integrate Firebase features like Analytics using Php

Comment: The logic of Firebase is that you don't need a custom (PHP) server and interact with the Firebase backend services directly from your Android app. There is no REST API for Google Analytics for Firebase. So you won't be able to call it from your PHP code. There is however an Android SDK (as well as an iOS SDK), so you can call it directly from your Android app.

Comment: Thanks a lot bro